# Specify what combinations shown as ligature while using FiraCode?

Tags: fonts

I'm using FiraCode in Emacs. Some ligature satisfies me and some don't.

For example, I really dislike this:

[image]

Is there any means to include or exclude specific ligatures?

Answer (score 2):

Most fonts have a built-in ligature table that controls when a glyph is used in place of other glyphs. For example, most fonts combine the 'f' and 'i' glyphs into an 'fi' glyph. For those fonts, you must either accept all the ligatures the font provides, turn all ligatures off, or edit the font to delete ligatures you don't like.

FiraCode is a little unusual in that it includes no (or very few; I've never actually taken a look inside) ligatures within the font itself. Instead it relies on the application to pick ligatures without any support from the ligature table inside the font. When you set up Emacs to use FiraCode, you copied and pasted a big chunk of code into your init file. This is the code that tells Emacs how to use FiraCode's ligature glyphs. All you have to do is edit it to remove the one that you don't like.